# Need to compress CSS and JavaScript via PHP but need to know performance implications and how to implement?

Tags: php, javascript, css, compression, server-side

I'm currently using PHP to include multiple css (or js) files into a single file (as well as compress the content using GZIP).

E.g. the HTML page calls resources like this...

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Concat.php?filetype=css&files=stylesheet1,stylesheet2,stylesheet3"></link>
<script src="Concat.php?filetype=js&files=script1,script2,script3"></script>

Example of my Concat.php file can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3687270/Concat.php (feel free to comment on any problems with the code)

But instead of having to open up my command prompt and running YUI Compressor manually on my CSS/JS files I want the Concat.php file to handle this for at least the CSS side of things (I say CSS only because I appreciate that YUI Compressor does minification of variables and other optimisations so it isn't feasible to replicate in PHP - but that is part 2 of my question).

I know this can be done with some Regex magic and I haven't a problem doing that.

So, my question has 2 parts, which are:

1.) What is the performance implications of having the server minify using preg_replace on a CSS file (or set of CSS files that could have a few hundred lines of code per file - normally it would be a lot less but I'm thinking that if the server compresses the file then I wouldn't have to worry too much about extra whitespace in my CSS)

2.) And how can I get the JavaScript files that are concatenated via my Concat.php file run through YUI Compressor? Maybe run via the server (I have direct access to the server so I could install YUI Compressor there if necessary), but would this be a good idea? Surely optimising on the server everytime a page is requested will be slow and bad for the server + increase bandwidth etc.

The reason this has come up is that I'm constantly having to go back and make changes to existing 'compressed/minified' JS/CSS files which is a real pain because I need to grab the original source files, make changes then re-minify and upload. When really I'd rather just have to edit my files and let the server handle the minification.

Hope someone can help with this.

Comment: Have you looked at http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: Have you checked that gzip(minify($stuff)) is significantly smaller than gzip(stuff)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you could use one of the **pre-built scripts** for that. They make use of YUI compressor as well as other solutions even if you can't run Java on the server.

The first one was probably [PHP Speedy](http://aciddrop.com/2008/02/01/speeding-up-your-website-just-became-499-easier/), which still works but has been abandoned.

A new one is [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/), which offers a lot of features including general caching solution depending on the server's capabilities (APC, Memcached, File cache).

Another advantage of these projects is that your URLs won't have **query strings** in them (contrary to your current method), which causes **troubles** in a lot of browsers **when it comes to caching**. They also take care of **gzipping** and handling **Expires headers** for your content.

So I definitely recommend that you try out one of these projects as they offer immediate positive effects, with some **simple** steps of configuration.

Comment: Cool. Minify sounds very useful! I'm assuming it works on windows and not just apache?

Comment: it is written in PHP so should be quite portable.

Answer (score 2):

If your webserver is Apache, you should use mod_concat and let the Apache take care of compression using gzip,

http://code.google.com/p/modconcat/

You should minify the JS just once and save the minified version on servers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i recommend you do it:

- Turn on GZIP for that specific folder (Web server level)
- Use one of the tools to strip out whitespace and concat the files. This will serve as a backup for search engines/proxy users who don't have gzip enabled. You'd then cache the output of this - so the expensive regex calls aren't hit again.

The above wont be very expensive CPU wise if you configure your server correctly. The PHP overhead won't really be much - As you'll have a cached version of the CSS, ie.

```
-- css.php --

if (!isset($_GET['f'])) {
  exit();
}

if (file_exists('path/to/cached/css/'.md5($_GET['f'])) {
  // just include that file...
  readfile('/path/to/cached/css/'.md5($_GET['f']));
  exit();
}

$files = explode(',', $_GET['f']);

ob_start();
foreach ($files as $file)
{
  readfile($file);
}

// set a header (including the etags, future expiration dates..)
Header(....);

echo ob_get_flush(); // remove whitespace etc..


// write a new cached file
file_put_contents('/path/to/cache/'.md5($_GET['f']));

exit();
```

You can then do **href="css.php?f=style.css,something.css,other.css"** the script will then make a cache file which is the md5 of those files included.

The above example isn't complete.. it's more pseudo really.